# Detect when a user interrupted UIScrollView animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have an app with a horizontal scrolling uiscrollview, it shows 3 subviews side by side. I am using Objective C.

When the user drags and releases, the code detects which is the closest subview and automatically scrolls to the nearest of the 3 subviews, making it fully centred.

This all works fine, except;

- When the scrollview is animating an auto-centering move, the user can interrupt by just tapping it (not dragging).
- This single tap halts the animation and scrollview, leaving it not centred on any of the 3 subviews.
- No delegate method I have found can detect when the animation is interrupted and then continue with centering.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe you can detect the tap, or when the touch ends, and then restart the centering animation?

Comment: Thank Picciano. What's the best way to detect the tap? Will it interfere with user interaction of the subviews?

Answer (score 0):

When you start the scroll animation with `setContentOffset:animated:` or `scrollToRectVisible:animated:`, its end will be marked by `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:`. If before that other delegate method is called, like `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` or `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` - that means that user interrupted your animatin with drag (or a tap).

What you want to do is restart your animation when user stops dragging - in `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` or `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`

Comment: Thanks mag_zbc! Problem is, `scrollViewWillbeginDragging:` doesn't trip with only a tap. It only triggers with a drag motion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again mag_zbc!

This really helped me find the solution.

I was overcomplicating the animation, checking for the current position both after the user finished dragging as well as when the animation finished.

To solve it, I just checked the current offset in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`:

-If the final offset was one of the three correct locations (auto-offset finished uninterrupted) then do nothing.

-If the offset was not one of the correct locations (animation was interrupted), then move again.